# Node.js Waterline ORM - lifecycle callbacks - invoke fails in rare cases

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm using a model similar to this in my application and the requirement is after creating the record, I want to the update the **owner** with the newly created record Id.

So I'm using the **afterCreate** method to do the same, but the strange behaviour is **afterCreate** method doesnot get invoked in rare cases. I have the same behaviour while creating the records manually, also in the mocha unit test. **Note: this is happening only in rare cases**. So, is there any best practise or am I doing anything wrong?

I've the solution for this as well.. What I've done is, instead of using **afterCreate** I'm doing the same in the controller action.. But just looking forward to know why this fails?

```
**sample.js**
module.exports = {

schema: true,

attributes: {

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    owner : {
       model: 'sample' 
    }
},

afterCreate : function(values, next) {
    sample.update({id:values.id},
                  {owner: values.id})
          .exec(function(err, result){

        if(err){
            next(err);
        }

    next();
    });
 }
};
```

Comment: FWIW, if `update().exec()` returns an error, you're calling the `next()` callback twice, which may lead to undefined/unwanted behaviour. Probably not the reason for the problem you're describing, but worth noting (and fixing).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
if(err) {
  next(err);
}
```

Should be:

```
if(err) {
  return next(err);
}
```

By not using `return` here, you are invoking `next()` twice, which is probably causing your problem.